# How to fix a wrong SVN directory structure?

Tags: svn, directory-structure

I am working on a project called `InvSim`. I use SVN for version control and to backup my files. Unfortunately, when I first set up the repository, I put the project directly into the `trunk` folder. In other words, my directory structure currently is the following:

```
trunk
    src
    input
    lib
```

What I would like to do is to instead have the directory structure to look like this:

```
trunk
    InvSim
        src
        input
        lib
```

From what I understand, this is the conventional to organize the SVN repository. Is there any way for me to fix the directory structure?

Comment: Do you want the entire history to reflect the latter directory structure?

Comment: That would definitely be nice if it were possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your working copy, you can use `svn mkdir InvSim` to make a new directory.  You can then use e.g. `svn mv src InvSim/` to move each of the original directories in turn.  Then do an `svn commit`.

Comment: This is helpful! I realized that I don't know how to run SVN from the command line. Currently I am using Subclipse (SVN plug-in for Eclipse). My SVN repository is hosted by Assembla, which according to [link](http://helpdesk.assembla.com/customer/portal/questions/660056-ssh-access-to-subversion-repo) does not support svn+ssh. What then should I do?

Comment: I managed to figure this out. In the "SVN Repository Exploring" perspective of Eclipse, it is possible to make a new folder, to move folders, etc. I also get all my previous commits and changes preserved!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new directory under trunk, and move everything you have to this directory. But your current structure is not unconventional, and there's probably no reason to change it.

Answer (score 0):

try renaming the folder using SVN rename option. Right click on folder -> SVN -> rename

Install Visual SVN, this is handy